# Selective catch for a closeable resource

Tags: java, checked-exceptions, autocloseable

This is more of a syntax / structuring issue. 
I'm working with JDBC: `Statement` and `ResultSet`, which means `SQLExceptions` are being thrown everywhere.

My code looks like this:

```
private static final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE";

public void lookAtMetadata() throws SQLException { 
  try (Statement myStatement = getStatement) 
  {
    try (ResultSet myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(MY_QUERY)) 
    {
      ResultSetMetadata metadata = myResultSet.getMetaData();
      // do other stuff with metadata
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good. 
But I want to throw a special Exception when `myStatement.executeQuery(MY_QUERY)` fails, like so:

```
ResultSet myResultSet = null;
try 
{
  myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(MY_QUERY);
  // get metadata and do stuff 
} catch (SQLException e) 
{
  throw new MySpecialException(e);
} finally 
{
  if (myResultSet != null) myResultSet.close();
}
```

The problem is, other operations involving `ResultSetMetaData` may also throw an `SQLException`, and I do NOT want to wrap those with `MySpecialException`.

Is there a way such that I can catch only the `SQLException` coming from query execution, and letting other `SQLExceptions` be thrown to the method caller? I would also like to properly close `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested try structure, with the inner try wrapping only the `executeQuery`. Add the catch handler to this inner try. Leave the outer try without a catch handler, so that it will propagate all other `SQLException`s as-is

```
ResultSet myResultSet = null;
try 
{
  try {
      myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(MY_QUERY);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new MySpecialException(e);
  }
  // get metadata and do stuff 
} finally 
{
  if (myResultSet != null) myResultSet.close();
}
```